# How to filter in NaN (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a pandas dataframe (df), and I want to do something like:

```
newdf = df[(df.var1 == 'a') & (df.var2 == NaN)]
```

I've tried replacing NaN with `np.NaN`, or `'NaN'` or `'nan'` etc, but nothing evaluates to True. There's no `pd.NaN`.

I can use `df.fillna(np.nan)` before evaluating the above expression but that feels hackish and I wonder if it will interfere with other pandas operations that rely on being able to identify pandas-format NaN's later.

I get the feeling there should be an easy answer to this question, but somehow it has eluded me.

Comment: NaN when compared to itself returns false. Have you tried `df.var2 != df.var2`?

Comment: There is actually a [`pd.NA`](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na) as of Pandas 1.0, not that that would be useful here.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This doesn't work because `NaN` isn't equal to anything, including `NaN`. Use `pd.isnull(df.var2)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the nice explanation. I see df.var2.isnull() is another variation on this answer.

Comment: Though that doesn't cover the case when you don't want to filter out NaN values. Sort of equilvalent to df.var2 != NaN

Comment: For others like me having @multigoodverse's observation, I found out there's also `pd.notnull()`. So you can keep `NaN` vals with `df.loc[pd.isnull(df.var)]` or filter them out with `df.loc[pd.notnull(df.var)]`.

Comment: You can also filter for nan with the unary operator (`~`). something like `df.loc[~pd.isnull(df.var)]`

Answer (score 164):

```
filtered_df = df[df['var2'].isna()]
```

This filters and gives you rows which has only `NaN` values in `'var2'` column.

Note: "[Series.isnull is an alias for Series.isna.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html)"

Answer (score 29):

```
df[df['var'].isna()]
```

where "var" is the column name

Comment: This is the same as [Gil's answer](/a/47629965/4518341) since ["Series.isnull is an alias for Series.isna."](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isnull.html) Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 10):

Pandas uses `numpy`'s NaN value. Use [`numpy.isnan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html) to obtain a Boolean vector from a pandas series.

Comment: You can't use numpy.isnan as an input

Comment: `np.isnan` doesn't work on "object" dtype. Plus, as of Pandas 1.0 (2020), Pandas has [`pd.NA`](//pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na), which NumPy can't handle, so it filters through to the result.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) here:

```
df.query('var2 != var2')
```

This works since `np.nan != np.nan`.