# Python: how to remove NaN from a polygon?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a shapefile that can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1tzCjp6OQQu_62yzNbuZyu_Z89c05iL6R?usp=sharing)

```
import geopandas as gpd
df_ = gpd.read_file(myFile)
df_.head()

    cluster population  index_righ  geometry
0   428277    1293          0       POLYGON ((-98.92807182102693 19.26524392904649...
1   429184    2863          0       POLYGON ((-99.29974187000285 19.32174386822139...
2   429375    3950          0       POLYGON ((-98.97854641702121 19.32403671280914...
3   429736    7122          0       POLYGON ((-99.08718538004899 19.30414966523743...
4   429880    9017          0       POLYGON ((-99.15351936519453 19.22180624334214...
```

Each of the `polygons` contains some `nan`.

How can I remove the `nan` values form them?

I am not able to access to the `POLYGON` values and for this reason, I am not able to do just a normal `dropna()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter in NaN (pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050141/how-to-filter-in-nan-pandas)

Comment: You mean that in the list of coordinates are NaNs?

Comment: @martinfleis yes

Comment: I can't see any NaNs in the file for some reason, but all geometries are invalid. Try using `buffer(0)`, that may fix the issue. It certainly makes polygons valid.

Comment: you want to remove the rows? how do you want to _remove_ the nans? maybe you want to replace them?

Comment: @NicolasGervais I want to remvoe all the nans from the `POLYGON` values

Comment: @martinfleis Can I do just `df_ = df_.buffer(0)`?

Comment: `df_.geometry = df_.buffer(0)` as buffer returns GeoSeries.