# Issue when using map function with conditions and NaN value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I have a column in data which looks like this:

```
Column
'Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace'
'Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace'
NaN
'Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace'
NaN
....
```

What I tried to do was to convert the string column into a boolean column i.e True for real value and False for NaN.

I tried to classify the value with the following command:

```
import numpy as np
star_wars[column] = star_wars[column].map(lambda x: True if (x != np.nan) else False)
star_wars[column].value_counts()
```

It returned that all the rows, either with true value and with nan value, to be true, which should not be the case.

I also tried to get the result through truthy/falsey value:

```
import numpy as np
star_wars[column] = star_wars[column].map(lambda x: True if (x) else False)
star_wars[column].value_counts()
```

But interestingly, when I use the hard code:

```
true_false = {
    "Star Wars: Episode I  The Phantom Menace": True,
    np.nan: False,
}

star_wars[column] = star_wars[column].map(true_false)
```

Then it works.

What's the issue for my solution? Or is there any document that I should refer to regarding to this issue? 
Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Also see: [Why is NaN not equal to NaN?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10034149/7851470)

Comment: Also: [How to filter in NaN (pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25050141/7851470)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `map` at all.

You can simply use [`df.Column.notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html), like this:

This is the `df`:

```
In [504]: df 
Out[504]: 
                                    Column
0  Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
1  Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
2                                      NaN
3  Star Wars: Episode I The Phantom Menace
4                                      NaN

In [506]: df = df.Column.notna()     
In [507]: df  
Out[507]: 
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Column, dtype: bool
```