# selecting nan values in a pandas dataframe using loc

Tags: pandas

I'm using pandas and trying to select all the rows with a `nan` in it from a column.
I've tried the following, but no joy, where am I going wrong?

```
aa.loc[((aa['_merge'] == 'right_only') & (aa['Context Interpretation'] == np.nan))]

aa.loc[((aa['_merge'] == 'right_only') & (aa['Context Interpretation'] == 'nan'))]
```

Comment: `.isna()` or `.isnull()`? [how-to-filter-in-nan-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25050141/how-to-filter-in-nan-pandas)

Comment: Give answer `aa.loc[((aa['_merge'] == 'right_only') & (aa['Context Interpretation']).isnull())]` and I'll accept.

Comment: @SpatialDigger - much to likely to be closed.